# Memory leak while writing out libjpeg image

Tags: linux, api, memory-leaks, libjpeg

I'm working inside a homegrown C++ framework, where one of the classes interfaces indirectly to libjpeg-8c.so (obtained as a Ubuntu 16.04 synaptic package).  I am running valgrind on my application, that eventually writes out image data as shown:

```
        ImageDescriptor* pOutputImageDesc, int outputQuality)
{
   //set up JPEG lib context
    /* Step 4: Start compressor
     * true ensures that we will write a complete interchange-JPEG file.
     * Pass true unless you are very sure of what you're doing.
     */
    jpeg_start_compress(&cInfo, TRUE);

    /* Step 5: while (scan lines remain to be written)
     *           jpeg_write_scanlines(...);

     * Here we use the library's state variable cInfo.next_scanline as the
     * loop counter, so that we don't have to keep track ourselves.
     * To keep things simple, we pass one scanline per call; you can pass
     * more if you wish, though.
     */

    rowStride = pInputImageDesc->width * pInputImageDesc->channels; // JSAMPLEs per row in image_buffer

    while (cInfo.next_scanline < cInfo.image_height)
    {
        /* jpeg_write_scanlines expects an array of pointers to scanlines.
         * Here the array is only one element long, but you could pass
         * more than one scanline at a time if that's more convenient.
         */
        rowPointerArray[0] = &inputBuffer[(cInfo.next_scanline * (rowStride))];
        static_cast<void>(jpeg_write_scanlines(&cInfo, rowPointerArray, 1));
    }

    // Step 6: Finish compression
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cInfo);

    //setup external image context

    // Step 7: release JPEG compression object
    // This is an important step since it will release a good deal of memory.
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cInfo);

    return 0;
}
```

Contrary to what the comment says, not all heap memory gets released.  Valgrind thinks differently in this malloc() trace

NOTE:  the trace below comes after linking against libjpeg-8d source

```
==6025==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6025==    by 0x4E4CDCE: empty_mem_output_buffer (jdatadst.c:131)
==6025==    by 0x4E4373E: dump_buffer_s (jchuff.c:274)
==6025==    by 0x4E4373E: emit_bits_s (jchuff.c:329)
==6025==    by 0x4E4373E: encode_one_block (jchuff.c:990)
==6025==    by 0x4E4373E: encode_mcu_huff (jchuff.c:1040)
==6025==    by 0x4E40DAB: compress_data (jccoefct.c:208)
==6025==    by 0x4E45B3F: process_data_simple_main (jcmainct.c:135)
==6025==    by 0x4E3EEE3: jpeg_write_scanlines (jcapistd.c:108)
==6025==    by 0x40DC4E: CompressRawToJpg(ImageDescriptor*, ImageDescriptor*, int) (ImageCaptureHelper.cpp:646)
==6025==    by 0x40DFB2: WriteJpgImage(char*, ImageDescriptor*) (ImageCaptureHelper.cpp:756)
==6025==    by 0x40CB18: Recognition::OutputImage::encode() (output_image.cpp:58)
==6025==    by 0x403AD4: main (testImgNorm.cpp:127)
```

So, after looking at the mem_empty_output_buffer() call, I'm thinking that this memory leak is due to:

1 - libjpeg-8c is badly written (it's certainly not clear how this fct and its caller interface either, but I digress); however, given how widely used this lib is, I doubt it.

2 - CompressRawToJpeg() should be calling free() on the malloc'ed buffer that's somewhere in *j_compress_ptr

3 - this is a real bug in libjpeg, and I should use another library.

I'm hoping someone out there that has encountered a similar issue, can offer a way for my code to write out jpeg images, without bleeding out 64K memory chunks (per file).

Thanks, Charles

Comment: Maybe solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32125043/1983398)? Hard to tell, because you didn't include all jpeg related code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that `jpeg_mem_dest()` allocates its own memory and ignores whatever you give it as the 2nd parameter:

```
uint8_t* output = NULL;
unsigned long outputSize = 0;
jpeg_mem_dest(&cInfo, &output , &outputSize);
```

So the leak happens when `free()` is not called at the end of the encoding process:

```
jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
free(output);
```